# Cannot find the module Angular2 Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

My vscode shows error in the line **Cannot find the module** and highlights **CreateTaskComponent** line of **app.module.ts**

My code

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
import { CreateTaskComponent} from './app/taskList/create-task.component';
@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, CreateTaskComponent ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

create-task.component.ts

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector:'create-task',
    templateUrl: 'app/taskList/create-task.component.html'

})
export class CreateTaskComponent{
        pageTitle : string ='Create a Task';

}
```

Folder structure is

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As your `app.module` already there in `app` folder, you can directly navigate through `taskList` folder.

```
import { CreateTaskComponent} from './taskList/create-task.component';
```

**OR**

```
import { CreateTaskComponent} from './../app/taskList/create-task.component';
```

Comment: Thanks Pankaj! Basic one. didnt catch it.